# create makefile for static library and executable simultaniously

Tags: c, makefile

I have 3 files which should included in static library (file1.c,file2.c,file3.c) and one file which should include the main function (main.c file) and linked to the static library.

I would like to create one makefile that create the library and then create the executable.

My base makefile is:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=file1.c file2.c file3.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
OUT=libctest.a
EXECUTABLE=hello
LDFLAGS = -static

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OUT): $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJECTS)

all:
    (CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE) main.c $(OUT)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) $(OUT)
```

The library is created but the executable doesn't created (all:   (CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE) main.c $(OUT))
Any idea what is needed?

Comment: (CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE) main.c $(OUT) Is this a typo in your question or in your actual makefile? It should be ${CC}

Comment: It's a typo, not working with dollar sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make will by default process the first target in the `Makefile`. In your case this is the `.c.o` target. To make `all` the default target move it to the top. Many people would prefer a style where `all` won't do anything but rather depend on others. Something along those lines:

```
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(OUT): $(OBJECTS)
    ar rcs $(OUT) $(OBJECTS)

$(EXECUTABLE): main.c $(OUT)
    (CC) -o $(EXECUTABLE) main.c $(OUT)
```

Comment: @Moti, also don't forget to add `$(EXECUTABLE)` to the `clean` artifact.

Comment: Just to clarify: the `.c.o` target is not considered the default target in the makefile: make chooses the first _explicit_ target in the makefile, and `.c.o` is a _suffix rule_ which is an implicit target, so it doesn't count.  As you might expect from the behaviour you saw, the first explicit target is `$(OUT)`, or `libctest.a`.